# Upload Numpy matrix from DataLab to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I have a numpy matrix as output in DataLab. How can I get it as a table in BigQuery?

so far it seems that I need to translate it into JSON, save in the Storage and upload from there.
Is there a simpler way to get this done?

Thanks

Comment: How is the structure of your matrix? NxN? Dense or sparse? What is the size? Do you have access to the python cloud api? You don't need to save it to storage, you could either [stream](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) or [upload from file](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert). In fact the latter is used by [pandas](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/blob/master/pandas_gbq/gbq.py#L560): it transforms the numpy vectors into Jsons and uses a `StringIO` buffer to upload the data to BQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simple solution with `pandas` package.

Need to transform the data to dataframe and use then `to_gbq` approach.

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq.html) is the documentation

The only downside is that that the records stay for hours if not days in BigQuery's `streaming buffer` and I'm not sure what is the impact of it.